# Add button to BrowseFragment

Tags: android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

I am developing an **Android TV** app using `Leanback support library`. I need to display a button in the top right corner (below the badge) of `BrowseFragment`. (as on below image)

[image: hep_img]

Here is the **layout** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="tv.bishan.com.videoapp.ui.ItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

How can I achieve this? Unable to find any solution from Google.

Comment: Could you show some screen shot or hint so that we can understand what exactly you want.

Comment: @jaydroider Check the improved question.

Comment: I think it is not supported if you are using the BrowseFragment template

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom TitleView and set it to the activity theme using the browseTitleViewLayout attribute.